# MVC4 and IIS Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic, basic-authentication

I have a legacy classic asp application that uses basic authentication.  I will be slowly migrating portions of the app to MVC4 and would like to 'drop them in' as they are completed -- this may take a long time and may never be fully complete. This means that I am 'sharing' the folder with the classic asp application.  Currently, the classic asp application has anonymous access turned off on in IIS6.

If I enable basic authentication and disable anonymous access for an MVC4 pplication in IIS6 is there any way for me to expose certain controller actions to anonymous, unauthenticated requests?  I can't turn on anonymous access at the application level in IIS because this now exposes the classis ASP pages to unauthenticated access.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to tag action methods with the [AllowAnonymous()] attribute.

I have **turned off anonymous access** and **enabled basic authentication** in IIS, however as soon as I attempt to access a resource (even a controller action tagged with AllowAnonymous), I am presented with the credentials dialog.  I am assuming this is the case because IIS cannot serve the request?  Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to separate those legacy and new applications in order for each has own authentication settings and fix internal link of your app. In this case legacy authentication might have a basic authentications enabled, though mvc project would allow anonymous actions.